# I am trying to install Magento 2.3 with PWA studio

Tags: magento2.3, pwa-studio

I am trying to install Magento 2.3 with PWA studio, but when I run below command I am getting an error

yarn run build

error

> ".graphqlconfig" file is not available in the provided config directory: /var/www/html/magento/pwa-studio
>   Please check the config directory.

Please help me!.

Answer (score 1):

are you using windows system. PWA does not support windows. Please install linux subsystem for windows to do that.